# Change column values for certain counter values

Tags: r

I am reading in data with a loop like so :

```
for(i in 1:2)
{
n= paste(i,".txt", sep="")
a<- sprintf("table%d", i, i)
data <- read.table(toString(n), header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
......
```

Then, I'm doing a bunch of stuff to data (getting trimmed means and such), then feeding into a master table which contains the mean values for each file. I'll do ANOVAs on the means later.

Anyway, I need to reverse the scores on certain files (those in the or statement) to make them equivalent ( a to b and b to a). This is how I've gone about it but it looks rather stupid, is there a neater syntax to do this?

```
if (i ==(2|4|6|7|9|11|14|16|18|19|21|23|25|28|30|32|34|36))
{
data$Reqresponse[data$Reqresponse == "a"] <- "nw"
data$Reqresponse[data$Reqresponse == "b"] <- "w"
data$Reqresponse[data$Reqresponse == "nw"] <- "b"
data$Reqresponse[data$Reqresponse == "w"] <- "a"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure your code does what you think it does.  I'm guessing you only want to run the if statement for values of i that match the numbers you listed?

Comment: Do you want something like `i %in% c(2,4,6,7,9,11,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,28,30,32,34,36)`?

Comment: @Dason:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-b7RmmMJeo

Comment: @sebastian-c That is my guess for what they want.

Comment: @Dason it seems to do if i doesn't match so I put the opposite numbers in (I'm survivin with a low IQ) , but yes I'd like to fix that

Comment: ok I'll change that bit. Do I need the 4 lines like I have or is there something a bit nicer?

Comment: @luke123 I'm not sure what you're saying but I was pointing out that 1 == (2|4) will return TRUE (any value except 0 on the left hand side will cause this to return TRUE).  You want to use %in% and your syntax most likely wasn't doing what you thought it was doing.

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to swap things out, you need to put them somewhere temporarily.

If you do  `a <- b` and then `b <- a`  they will both end up with the same value. 
You need to instead do  `TMP <- a` `a <- b` `b <- TMP`

As for the `or` statement, you are probably looking for `%in%` as @sebastian-c points out.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is just how I was approaching things before I discovered `plyr`. Here is how I approach similar situations now. There are probably people who can show you quicker ways, but here is how I would tackle your situation.

```
library(plyr)

#Assuming all your files are in the working directory
filenames <- list.files(".", ".txt") 
#Assuming your files are "1.txt" etc
file.index <- sub("([0-9]+).txt", "\\1", filenames) 
#reads in all the files
import <- mdply(filenames, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") 
#Assigns the index to each group of rows from each file
import$index <- file.index[import$X1] 

#Gives you one big table to work with.
#Fix your reversing issue
import$Reqresponse.alt[import$Reqresponse == "a" & import$index %in% c(2,4,6,7,9,11,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,28,30,32,34,36)] <- "b"
import$Reqresponse.alt[import$Reqresponse == "b" & import$index %in% c(2,4,6,7,9,11,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,28,30,32,34,36)] <- "a"

import$Reqresponse <- import$Reqresponse.alt
import$Reqresponse.alt <- NULL

#Now your table should be clean
#You can use plyr to to summarise your data

import.summary <- ddply(import, .(index), summarise,
                        demo.mean = mean(demo), #functions you want to summarise with go here
                        demo.sd = sd(demo),
                        #etc
                        )
```

Obviously I don't have your actual data to work with to check I haven't made mistakes, but this is just the sort of workflow that is functioning very nicely for me now.

Comment: It's tough reading your comments when you put them on the same line of the code.  You might consider moving the comments to the line before the code...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll take it on board